# JSP can not access controllers in Spring and it always shows 404?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and this question might be asked before but I can not find a accurate answer after two days. I am almost desperate.

My expectation is that when I click on  [Homepage.jsp, it can redirect to login.jsp. But the fact is that I can display Homepage.jsp correctly when I run the project. When I click on , it shows 404 error. Here in the following you can see configuration:](/hello)

[My project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RydLz.png) 
web.xml

```
    <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>HomePage.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.KameraVision.controller" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="datasource"  
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />  
    <property name="url" 
value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/KameraVision"/>        
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>  
    <property name="password" value="md5c4cbdf09352c99860fc9ba841f41af83" />  
</bean>   
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
     <props>
        <prop key="/hello">loginController</prop>          
     </props>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="loginController" 
class="com.KameraVision.controller.LoginController" />
</beans>
```

Homepage.jsp

LOGIN

LoginController.java

```
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;


public class LoginController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value="hello")
     protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
          model.addObject("message", "Welcome!");
          return model;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.  Change  `InternalResourceViewResolver` (make sure that prefix is:  /WEB-INF/jsp/ with the "/" at the end of jsp) folder:**

```
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> The Controller

**2.1  Option 1 with @Controller annotation (removing the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping from the xml):**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
     protected ModelAndView myHelloRequest()  {
          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
          model.addObject("message", "Welcome!");
          return model;
       }
}
```

**2.2  Option 2: SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**

```
public class LoginController extends AbstractController {

    @Override //it is not necesary to define a RequestMapping here because your are using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
     protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hello");
          model.addObject("message", "Welcome!");
          return model;
       }
}
```

**3.  It is very important!! Finally make sure that you have a `hello.jsp` in your `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder**

Comment: Do I need to remove the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping?

Comment: you can use SimpleUrlHandlerMapping if you want too, I just add some change to the answer in order to give you more informatión, also you can check an example here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/

Comment: I would adopt your answer although my question is still not solved yet. I have a anchor in HomePage.jsp: <a href="hello">. Is it correct?

Comment: first try to get access to hello in the browser, for example http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello  then if that works your app is running ok, and finally <a href="/hello">

Comment: I put a hello.jsp under WEB-INF/jsp/ folder. I tried to access via typing localhost:8080/KameraVision/jsp/hello.jsp, but it does not work. Do I need to configure other files?

Comment: nop, since your are using spring mvc there is not necesary to call the .jsp directly, because spring mvc will handle it through the handler controller that you define <prop key="/hello">loginController</prop>.  Just use this http://localhost:8080/KameraVision/hello  spring mvc will handle it at show the .jsp file

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `RequestMapping` annotation, I don't believe that it works together with `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, so that may be causing an issue.

Also consider utilizing Spring Security, as this would handle your login redirect for you for any resource that needs authorization.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/

Comment: Have you tried removing the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` bean and just using `@RequestMapping(value="/hello")`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried that. But the problem still exists

Comment: I am just curious, is there a reason you want to use dispatcherServlet.xml to declare your beans?

Comment: You can annotate your `LoginController` with `@Controller` and also remove the bean definition in your xml

Comment: Take a look at some documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

I hope this helps!

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you